# Express error middleware sending response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

In my `express` application when the error middleware is reached it still executes the second middleware function after `res.json`. The [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) says that:

> The methods on the response object (res) in the following table can send a response to the client, and terminate the request-response cycle. If none of these methods are called from a route handler, the client request will be left hanging.

Where `res.json` is one of the methods in the table which would terminate the request-response cycle. Also I don't call next in my express error middleware

```
router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'fail: email already exists'
    });
});


//test still gets logged even though the express error middleware is executed
router.post('/', (req, res , next) => {
    console.log('test');

});
```

### Question:

Why is the second `express` middleware still executed even though I don't call next in the error middleware and execute `res.json()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation on error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) you must specify the error handling middleware **last** for it to work properly.

It is likely that by having that with an error signature that is is getting confused.

Comment: so all the error handling middleware has to be defined at the end?

Comment: Yes. You have to always have the error handling be the last middleware in the chain. It's a bit of a goofy requirement I think, but that's the way it is.